# UDP checksum calculation

Tags: c, network-programming, udp, checksum

The UDP header struct defined at /usr/include/netinet/udp.h is as follows

```
struct udphdr
{
  u_int16_t source;
  u_int16_t dest;
  u_int16_t len;
  u_int16_t check;
};
```

What value is stored in the check field of the header? How to verify if the checksum is correct? I meant on what data is the checksum computed? (Is it just the udp header or udp header plus the payload that follows it?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The UDP checksum is performed over the entire payload, *and* the other fields in the header, *and* some fields from the IP header. A pseudo-header is constructed from the IP header in order to perform the calculation (which is done over this pseudo-header, the UDP header and the payload). The reason the pseudo-header is included is to catch packets that have been routed to the wrong IP address.

Basically, at the receiving end, all the 16-bit words of the headers plus data area are added together (wrapping at 16 bits) and the result is checked against `0xffff`.

On the sending side, it's a little more complex. A one's complement sum is performed on all the 16-bit values then the one's complement (i.e., invert all bits) is taken of that value to populate the checksum field (with the extra condition that a calculated checksum of zero will be changed into all one-bits).

The one's complement sum is *not* just the sum of all the one's complement values. It's a little more complex.

Basically, you have a running 16-bit accumulator starting at zero and you add every 16-bit value to that. Whenever one of those additions results in a carry, the value is wrapped around and you add one to the value again. This effectively takes the carry bit of the 16-bit addition and adds it to the value.

---

> As an aside, and this is pure conjecture on my part but this could probably be efficiently done by use of the `ADC` (add with carry) instruction rather than `ADD` (surprisingly enough, add), or whatever equivalent instructions were available on your CPU at the time.
>
> If there were no carry, `ADC` would just add the zero bit from the carry. In the days when this stuff was done (and yes, unfortunately, I *am* that old), memory was far more of a constraint than speed, not so much the case nowadays, so saving a few bytes in your code could well elevate you to the level of demi-god-emperor-of-the-universe :-)

---

Note that you never had to worry about carry the second time around (or a carry of two with the next `ADC` if you're using that method mentioned in the previous paragraph) since the two largest 16-bit values, when summed, produce (truncated from `0x1fffe`) `0xfffe` - adding one to that will never cause another carry.

Once the calculated one's complement sum is calculated, has its bits inverted and is inserted into the packet, that will cause the calculation at the receiving end to produce `0xffff`, assuming no errors in transmission of course.

It's worth noting that the payload is always padded to ensure there's an integral number of 16-bit words. If it *was* padded, the length field tells you the actual length.

[RFC768](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc768.html) is the specification which details this.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was a bit confused about the Pseudo-Header part..but then the RFC cleared the air.

Comment: "All the 16-bit words of the headers (where the UDP checksum is zero) are added and the one's complement (i.e., invert all bits) is what gets put into the checksum field." No, what the RFC says would lead to "All the one's complements (i.e., invert all bits) of the 16-bit words of the headers (where the UDP checksum is zero) are added and the one's complement of that is what gets put into the checksum field."
Otherwise perfect answer +1.

Comment: This isn't right. "One's complement sum" doesn't mean take the one's complement of each word and add them together. It means that you add the words together, and when a carry bit is produced, you add 1 to the running sum. See http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54379.html .

Comment: Thanks, @Jim, a bit more research turns up that you're dead right. I was going to say that I was dead wrong but my ego stepped in at the last minute and disallowed it :-). If you think the updated answer is still wrong, please let me know. Cheers.

Comment: An interesting note about the one's complement checksum, which may have a lot to do with why it was chosen, is that swapping the byte order of the words to be summed will swap the byte order of the sum.

Comment: It's good to know that I'm not the only one confused about the term "one's complement sum". Any place I go, that term is just thrown out there without much of an explanation, but it really isn't that simple, is it?

Comment: @paxdiablo: If I read you right, it is possible to validate a checksum using regular unsigned binary addition and discarding the carry. But in the script of my uni course, a one's complement addition is also used to validate the checksum, not just to calculate it.

Comment: @paxdiablo re: Use ADC for speed -- See this article - http://locklessinc.com/articles/tcp_checksum/ for a pretty deep examination of that very question.

Answer (score 3):

A nice and easy to understand example of UDP checksum calculation is done by Gerd Hoffmann.

You can google for "net-checksum.c Gerd Hoffmann" 
or look at the file here:

https://gist.github.com/fxlv/81209bbd150abfeaceb1f85ff076c9f3

You can use `net_checksum_tcpudp` function, feed it the UDP payload length, proto, src and dst IPs and then the UDP payload itself and it will do the right thing.

At the end you have to call `htons()` on the checksum and you're good.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching the net for some code which will calculate the udp header (with the pseudo ip header as mentioned above).

Finally I found the open-bsd dhclient packet.c:

https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/sbin/dhclient/packet.c

check out the function `assemble_udp_ip_header()`

Comment: You've linked to DragonflyBSD, although that source file is derived from OpenBSD.  Here's the canonical OpenBSD git link: https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/sbin/dhclient/packet.c