# .NET 4.5 Error detection in communication (CRC?)

Tags: .net, communication, crc

I have a quite simple communication leveraging UDP protocol. I would like to add some error checking (probably a hash function which woudn't be influenced by previous messages). I know about the CRC function, however in the implementations I have found the CRC calculation was influenced by previous messages which isn't appropriate in my case as some data in my UDP communication might not arrive. Does anyone know about a downloadable CRC that would satisfy my needs (perhaps I would be able to write a CRC check myself, however I am unfortunately a little bit short on time)? Are there any other known options (a class/function which is already in .NET Framework 4.5 would be great).

Thanks for any efforts.

Comment: Why CRC isn't good then? You can apply it per UDP package separately.

Comment: You mean to reset the actual polynomial of CRC after every message to its default value (That is how I would do it in the implementations I found)? Isn't it a bit rough? Well since time is against me I guess I could go with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general I would like to recomment to use TCP. There you don't need to care about that the packages come in the right order nor you need to think about checksums (because they are [build in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure)). TCP has all that build in and if a package get lost TCP triggers also a retransmission or the lost package.

However you normally don't need to implement such a CRC check even UDP has a build in checksum. See also the [packet structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Packet_structure) in wikipedia.

If you really want to add a crc [check this implementation](http://damieng.com/blog/2006/08/08/calculating_crc32_in_c_and_net) on damieng.com, it looks fine, but I did not check it.

Comment: I need some safer checksum computation - These auto-checksums use just addition of all bits or something similar to it, isn't that right?

Comment: Oh and it is very benefical for me to use UDP because of speed... I'll check the implementation you linked.

Comment: Which uses case do you have that the TCP handshake is a real problem for you? The autochecksums are in each package in a underlaying level, so wou properbly won't ever see a corupt package. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1480600/995926) about UDP checksums.

Comment: Well TCP isn't a real problem, I just wanted to have a little faster communication of my real-time data transmition as I don't need to use acknowledge messages in most packets and to accept every packet. But I just need to be very sure that there won't be corrupted data, I know that I probably won't ever encounter an error in UDP(/TCP) packets with its default checksums as they are.

Comment: Oh ye and I looked at the link. So since the auto-UDP checksum isn't just sum-based I could perhaps go with that... Thanks

Comment: Oh yes, UDP has a built-in checksum, it doesn't protect all fields though.