# Calculate UDP layer checksum

Tags: c#, .net, packet, checksum

I want to modify packets I have and send these packets through the network card. To do this, I need to calculate my UDP layer `Checksum`.

So I found [this](http://cyb3rspy.wordpress.com/2008/03/27/ip-header-checksum-function-in-c/) function that takes an array and returns the `Checksum`, but I have two small questions:

1. UDP layer has 8 bytes: 2 source port, 2 destination port, 2 length and 2 checksum.
   the function that I found needs to be called with an array, so should I send this function my 6 bytes array with or without the 2 bytes of checksum?
2. This function mentions that it calculates IP checksum, this is also fit to calculate `UDP` checksum ?

   Edit:

I found [this](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-calculate-iptcpudp-checksumpart-2-implementation/) article that calculate IP/TCP/UDP checksum, can i have help to convert the code calculate UDP checksum into c# ?

Comment: Did you check wikipedia? Nice page with algos and all.

Comment: IP checksums only use the header. TCP/UDP checksums use the header and data.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting it to zero? According to RFC 768 it is optional.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc768

"An all zero transmitted checksum value means that the transmitter generated no checksum (for debugging or for higher level protocols that don't care)."

If you really want to calculate it you could try looking at the     assemble_udp_ip_header function in FreeBSD: http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/sbin/dhclient/packet.c?view=markup .

You shouldn't call it with just a 6 byte array because the checksum procedure should be run on the pseudo header. While you could probably use the function that you mentioned on the pseudo header, I suspect that it has a bug where it can access past the end of the array if the length parameter is not even.

The checksum that you computed is incorrect because it needs to be computed on the psuedo header. You are missing fields such as the protocol, ip address source, ip address destination, and the actual payload. You are also only writing to 6 out of the 8 bytes that you allocated.

Answer (score 0):

The author of that post says in his comments

"...The first parameter is the byte array containing the IP Header packet (already formed but with the checksum field [two bytes] set to zero)."

So you should set the two checksum bytes (bytes 7 and 8) to zero, then send all 8 bytes of your header to have the checksum computed.

As for UDP/IP checksums, they are two different things and the author stated this calculation was specifically for IP header checksum creation.

Comment: so i can use this function for the UDP checksum ?

Comment: No. As stated in the last sentence, the author said this was was IP header checksum. This will undoubtedly produce the wrong value for a UDP checksum. See the this SO post for information on UDP checksums: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480580/udp-checksum-calculation